# Multi touch behaviour in ICS

Tags: android, touch

I am working on a project in which I want to modify android 4.0 framework in such a way that when I do a multi touch all the previous touches should be cancelled and the current touch should be counted as down event simultaneously.

Current behaviour is like for multi touch, first cancel event is been issued and for the next touch event only pointer down is been issued.

But I am not sure which Class/method to modify and what to modify. Please suggest me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to modify the framework from AOSP? What did you tried already?

Comment: After some digging,i got to know that I have to modify in WindowManagerService.java and InputMnager.java since they are giving the touch events to ViewGroup.java but I am not sure what to modify  in it.

Comment: can you clarify your scenario a little bit more ? you can try to provide us an example usage of your goal.

Comment: Suppose there are two touch events in which when I do a 2nd touch,I want to cancel all the previous ones and want to give Action Down event for the current touch(2nd touch).